# sed fails for regular expression

Tags: regex, sed

I have a CSV-like formatted file, e.g.:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

and I am trying to reformat it to get:

```
A:2/B:4/C:6
A:3/B:5/C:7
```

so I wrote a little `sed` script:

```
sed -r 's/[0-9]+,\([0-9]+\),[0-9]+,\([0-9]+\),[0-9]+,\([0-9]+\).*/A:\1\/B:\2\/C:\3/'
```

but it reports an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 92: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS
```

why doesn't it work and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are escaping the `()`. `\(` is very different to `(`.

When it is escaped, `\(`, it will match a literal "`(`" in the string. Capture Groups use `()` but they must not be escaped.

Therefore, you have no capture groups, and so there is an error back-referncing Capture Group #3, since it does not exist.

You should change this, `\([0-9]+\)`, to this, `([0-9]+)`:

```
[0-9]+,([0-9]+),[0-9]+,([0-9]+),[0-9]+,([0-9]+).*
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/pG8kC4/1)</kbd>

---

### A More Efficient RegEx

Your RegEx was quite innefficient. It can be shorted to this:

```
\d+,(\d+),\d+,(\d+),\d+,(\d+).*
# VS #
[0-9]+,([0-9]+),[0-9]+,([0-9]+),[0-9]+,([0-9]+).*
```

And you can use the same substitute statement.

The reason this works is because `\d` is a shorthand method of writing `[0-9]`, it is `3` digits shorter (and considering the number of times you have written `[0-9]`, this saves a *lot* of space)

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/pC0iG1/2)</kbd>

Comment: @Shafizadeh Thank you!

Comment: Note that the bit about `(` vs `\(` only applies because you're using `-r`.  Without `-r`, the meanings are reversed.  Every tool understands a slightly different flavor of regular expression syntax - in the case of `sed`, several different ones you get to choose among.  So be careful.

Comment: Should it be `\d' or `\d+` in your shortened version?

Comment: @Grzenio Well, if the number could be 2 digits, `\d+`. Thanks, I'll update the answer!

Comment: Despite what some online tool may think is a valid regexp, there is no version of sed that would interpret `\d` as meaning "a digit" and please note @MarkReed's comment as it is critically important when using sed. If you want to make the solution briefer use something like `([0-9]+,([0-9]+),){2}[0-9]+,([0-9]+).*`

Answer (score 2):

With `-r`, regular expressions use the "extended" syntax, under which capturing parentheses shouldn't be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{printf "A:%s/B:%s/C:%s\n", $2, $4, $6}' file
```

Using `-F,` allows to specify the field delimiter and splits the input lines by a comma. `printf` reassembles the output like you desire.

Comment: That is what a colleague suggested and it clearly works. I wanted to figure out why this sed command doesn't work though.

Comment: Like others said, either use `\(...\)` or pass `-r` to sed

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be content in regex like this `\([0-9]+\)`. Here you are escaping `(` and `)`, so it's not actually a capturing group and hence cannot be referenced back.

Try `([0-9]+)` or `(\d+)`.